# Can the comma be omitted after "during 1983"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

In the sentence, "During 1983 temperatures set records," would it be okay to omit the comma after "during 1983"?

Comment: Absolutely. Commas are mostly a matter of style anyway.

Comment: I'm not really convinced by "during" in general. I don't think I would use it this way. I'd pretty universally use "in". I'm also not particularly fond of the attribution of action. "Record [high? low?] temperatures were experienced/recorded"... the temperatures didn't really set the record. The record is a human construct.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, the comma may be omitted.

> During 1983 temperatures set records.
>
> During 1983, temperatures set records.

Both sentences would be understood to mean the same, but the comma shouldn't be omitted, because "during 1983" is an [introductory clause](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/).

Comment: If both sentences would be understood to mean the same thing, why do you think the comma should not be omitted?

Comment: @Hectorvon Your italicized sentence is nearly unintelligible to me. Can you edit that?

Comment: A comma is very helpful here.  Otherwise one has to ponder how to parse the text.  Consider:  *During 2000 thunderstorms caused major problems in Winnipeg.*  vs.  *During 2000 thunderstorms scientists discovered that over 200 of the storms spawned tornadoes*.  It is very hard to parse these sentences without commas, so I would use commas for clarity.  It's not the reader's job to figure out what I meant, if I can help.

Comment: @Rhythmatic I cannot edit an old comment, but I could delete it.